# Update query using select statement of updating table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

In Mssql i want to update a column **col1** in table named **Table1** using select query which returns **col1** from **Table1** and add 1 to it.
So i used the following code

```
update Table1 set col1=(select col1 from Table1) + 1;
```

But when i used it says you cannot target same table.Is there any ways to work out this function.
Please help to find it out.

Thanks in advsnce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like that

```
     update Table1 set col1= col1 + 1;
```